# Retrieve a value from a Query with ADODB

Tags: vb.net, adodb

I'm learning to adapt code that I use in VBA to work in VB.Net, And I'm having an hard time to figure how to get a value from a query and store it in a String.

I know the query works but unlikne VBA when I try to store it in the String "Valor", an error happens, like shown in the error image.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim VD As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Valor As String

    VD.ConnectionString = "DSN=XXX;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX;"

    VD.Open()
    RS = VD.Execute("SELECT Cod_PA FROM Tab_SERVICO WHERE Cod_PA='VIADELMAR'")
    If Not (RS.BOF And RS.EOF) Then
        Valor = RS.Fields("Cod_PA").Value
    Else
        Valor = "Não existe!"
    End If
    RS.Close()
    VD.Close()

    MsgBox(Valor)

End Sub
```

[image: error]

Comment: This looks like VB6 code. Are you trying to port it to VB.NET?

Comment: Yes, something like that. It's working fine until I try to store the value in a string... I'll try your way tomorrow at work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Example()
    Dim VD As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection ' ADODB.Connection
    Dim CMD As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand ' ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Valor As String

    VD.ConnectionString = "DSN=XXX;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX;"
    VD.Open()

    CMD.Connection = VD
    CMD.CommandText = "SELECT Cod_PA FROM Tab_SERVICO WHERE Cod_PA='VIADELMAR'"

    ''Two (or more) possible choices for getting data: 

    ''Option 1
    ''If you Then just want 1 col / 1 row, you can simply .ExecuteScalar()
    Valor = CMD.ExecuteScalar  'Simple. Sometimes too simple.

    ''Option 2 - If your query will return multiple columns and rows then 
    ''           you need to get data with a DataAdapter and store it 
    ''           in a DataSet or DataTable.  Example: (uncomment below)
    'Dim DT As New DataTable
    'Dim DA As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(CMD)
    'DA.Fill(DT)
    'If (DT.Rows.Count > 0) Then
    '    Valor = DT.Rows(0)("Cod_PA")
    'Else
    '    Valor = "Não existe!"
    'End If
    ''clean up. Just like: Set VD = Nothing
    'DA.Dispose()
    CMD.Dispose()
    VD.Close()
    VD.Dispose()

    MsgBox(Valor)
End Sub
```

Comment: I just had to change from OleDb to Odbc in my case and fixed `If Not (DT.Rows.Count > 0) Then` to `If (DT.Rows.Count > 0) Then` and its working fine. Thanks for the Help.

Comment: OleDb or Odbc mostly depends on your connection string.  You were right about my mistake with the `if` condition. I corrected my code. Also, if this answers your question, would you mind "accepting" this answer (click the checkmark next to this answer)?

Comment: Done :), and forgot to mention `Valor = DT.Rows(0)("Cod_PA").Value` doesn't need the `.Value` or else an error will happen. Maybe you'll want to fix that too in your code.